# Authentication with admin password problem

Tags: authentication

I have read quite a few of the answers to password problems but am completely new to Ubuntu and can't figure this out.

I bought my computer (a Dell vostro) a few days ago, and I was trying to install some apps and it asks for an authentication code. I got as far as to check user account (only one, admin) and it doesn't seem to have a password.

I read a thread about setting a password but I don't know what "Windows Key" or "Terminal" are, so could someone please explain this?

Comment: Have you tried entering your normal user password?

Comment: Blondie has to switch back to windows and write her password in her mobile notes :p

Comment: Haha you are So funny odinRW. Sorry if the post wasn't clear. There is no password set. I have no user password and there is no password set when I check the user accounts.
Warren Hill, yes I read that but I really don't want to start messing with the computer as have no proper skills! Does it still need a reset if there is no password set?

Comment: Aha! Called the guys who I bought it from and they told me the password (password!!!) -wonder why they didn't tell me that when I bought the computer. Thanks for everyone who took the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

So there are something called sudoers in Linux (it's like when you create user in Windows and can choose if they are admin or normal users). So when you install apps from terminal the command should be like (in terminal)

```
sudo apt-get install package
```

Some applications and packages are in the software center. You can look them up there. When you will be asked for password it will be your user password not the root password. The root is the GOD of GOD's in Linux. I don't set a root password at all because you don't need it. If blondie like reading then go and check [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/)

Terminal is a cmd like. It's a way to control all your system (including installing/removing/updating packages). It's the key when you use Linux :D